# CFML Design Pattern resources?

Tags: design-patterns, coldfusion, railo, openbd, cfml

As with all development, CFML via [ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/), [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/) or [OpenBD](http://openbluedragon.org/) we run into common programming problems.  For these problems must programmer turn to patterns (or anti-patterns).  However the classic resources like [GOF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) and the modern [Head First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) books both tend to focus on Java.

While java is beautiful in its own right, all three cfml engines are essentially java applications, that said not all or even many design patterns can or should be used in the java way when writing cfml.

I would like to know what resources/patterns you have found useful when working with cfml?  Or what you changed adapting a java or smalltalk pattern for use in cfml?

Personally I found both of these presentations to be interesting:

[CFMeetup: Design Patterns and ColdFusion](https://admin.na3.acrobat.com/_a204547676/p41374019/) By Sean Corfield

and

[Design Patterns](https://admin.adobe.acrobat.com/_a200985228/p96036603/) By Cameron Childress

**Update:**

Stumbled upon [cfdesignpatterns.com](http://www.cfdesignpatterns.com), looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a site you may want to check [Object-Oriented ColdFusion](http://www.objectorientedcoldfusion.org/). Its still a work in progress, but it may help.

regards,
larry

Comment: Even for a work in progress this site is great!  I haven't written coldfusion in a couple years but looked through this site it has solid explanation and code samples thanks!  I hope it helps others write great CFML

Answer (score 3):

Head First Design Patterns is an excellent book. Though it's focus seems Java based, it's the principles within that matter. CFML doesn't lend itself well to pure OO development, with much ongoing debate of that going on within the ColdFusion community, but that doesn't mean that patterns and frameworks are without merit.

It comes down to what works best for your application, and for you as a programmer. I like studying the various frameworks that are out there, to get insight into someone else's approach. I personally like to work within an MVC style, which lends itself to good maintainability and structure. I've used most of the available frameworks, in one way or another, over the past several years. Each has their strengths and weaknesses.

Patrick's SOLID reference looks intriguing too.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [SOLID](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/02/12/getting-a-solid-start) principles more helpful than anything else. If you understand the SOLID principles, you'll write better code in any language, and be able to use design patterns more effectively.